# Jquery Superbox + jScrollPane Problem

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

Hello guys and thanks for read this:
Well im getting this problem, im trying to use Superbox and jScrollPane.
I got some inline content that nicely Superbox load (As modal) but no scrollbars (jScrollPane) appears so i cant scroll the content. If helps some code:

HOW SUPERBOX JSCROLLPANE:

```
$(function(){
            $.superbox.settings = {
                closeTxt: "Close",
                loadTxt: "Loading...",
                nextTxt: "Next",
                prevTxt: "Previous"
            };
            $.superbox();
                   $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(); 

        });
```

HOW I CALL/OPEN THE LIGHTBOX:

```
<li><a href="#about" rel="superbox[content]">About</a></li>
```

THE HTML FOR INLINE CONTENT:

```
<div id="infos" style="display:none;">
            <div id="acerca" class="scroll-pane">
            <h2>Content mode</h2>
            <p>Generates a box containing an element of the page.</p>
</div>
        </div>
```

Thanks for your time and knowledge!!

Answer (score 0):

You call `$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();` but you don't show an element on your page with a class of `scroll-pane`. There must be something matching the selector that you apply jScrollPane to.

Also, you probably only want to initialise jScrollPane once the superbox has opened. I had a quick look at the superbox page and unfortunately they don't seem to provide any events so I'm not sure if there is a way to find out when a superbox has been opened. You could try this instead:

```
$('#infos').show().jScrollPane().hide();
```

This will temporarily show the info box and initialise jScrollPane on it (you can't initialise jScrollPane on hidden elements) and then hide it again. Then when superbox shows it jScrollPane should be in place...

Comment: Hi vitch thanks a lot for your reply: please check this link http://tdpworkspace.org/conocearica/ and click in the word "ACERCA" JScrollpane has an strange behavior :/

Comment: It looks like the jScrollPane needs to be initialised after the superbox has been shown... The only way to do this cleanly is if superbox has some sort of "load" event but that doesn't appear to exist. You could try adding a click listener to the link and initialising jScrollPane in that?

Comment: Oh i see sorry but im not a coder (plus im a little dummie) so please could you give me hand with that? some example code ill be great.

Comment: Hi guys if this helps someone i solved using the Ajax[] funcion and make a href to an anchor, thats solve everything. Thanks to me :D